# Socket.io Cannot GET /socket.io/ 404

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I really can't get socket.io to work after deployment.

**Backend:**

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "15mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "15mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("My app API"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const SOCKET_IO_PORT = process.env.SOCKET_IO_PORT || 5500;

let server = app.listen(SOCKET_IO_PORT, () => {
  console.log("Socket.io server running on port :" + SOCKET_IO_PORT);
});

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: { origin: "https://myapp.pages.dev" },
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL)
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port : ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

**Frontend:**

```
socket.current = io("https://myapp-api-production.up.railway.app");
    socket.current?.on(
      "getMessage",
      (...) => {
        ...
      }
    );
```

**Browser network tab:**

> Request URL: https://myapp-api-production.up.railway.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OO7eSMV
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Status Code: 404

Response:

> Cannot GET /socket.io/

Server deployment log:

- Socket.io server running on port :5698
- Server running on port :
  7777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating two separate HTTP servers (by calling `app.listen()` twice). It looks like your frontend code is targeting the Express server, and not the `socket.io` server.

My suggestion would be to just use one HTTP server listening on `PORT`:

```
let server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port :" + PORT);
});
```

(and remove the call to `app.listen()` in the Mongoose `then()` handler).

Comment: Great suggestion. Everything works as before deployment. Thanks a lot.